# What is the XStream imitate use case

Tags: cyclejs, xstream-js

The docs go over imitate use case, but I don't understand the example made. Where would you call a Parent function, is it like recursive? I'd like to see what the model function looks like, and what the child gets out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`imitate` is meant to create a cycle in the graph of streams connected by operators, that's the use case. It would often be seen when building a state stream.

However, nowadays we have a solution in Cycle.js called `@cycle/state` which solves for that use case, and in Cycle.js there is no need for `imitate` anymore. We would like to deprecate `imitate` but we have heard some people still depend on it, so we're postponing the deprecation.

(I'm the creator of xstream and Cycle.js)